# jpanel overeride the other compoent zorder in java swing application

Tags: java, swing, arcobjects

I am making a network managemant system with arcgis map using arcobject java and swing application but the problem is that one panel zindex override the others. the result is that Jpopup menu and tab menu list not showing in the main frame.
I think its Zcompent order problem. I have hanlde these problems in javascipt with increasing the zindex of corresponding div and span but in java swing application its very difficult to find the problem.

Kindly suggest the possible solution. please see the image to understand the problem in deatils.

- [image: List item][image]

Comment: I'm think that you have look at  [public void setComponentPopupMenu(JPopupMenu popup)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29)

Comment: Could be that your "MapPanel" is an AWT component which causes problems in older versions of the JDK.

Comment: It's more likely to be an issue with mixing heavy weight (AWT) and light weight (Swing) compnents. AWT components don't have a concept of z-ordering and can cause issues when mixed with swing. If your up for some work, you could check out the MapView from SwingLabs